# What is the regex for "A float with 2 decimal places, and only allows increments of 0.25"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to match the following inputs:

```
 .25
 .50
 .75
 1.25. 1.50, 1.75 are allowed (increments of .25)
(2.0/2.00, 3.0/3.00, 4.0/4.00, 5.0/5.00 - not allowed)
```

The integer parts allowed are 1-9
Hence 10.00 or 10.25... are not allowed

Special inputs not allowed are: 0, 0.0 
The whole numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8 and 9 are allowed while 1.0/1.00, 
      2.0/2.00, 3.0/3.00...and so on are not allowed

Also, no, positive or negative signs before the number are allowed.

Hence

### 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 should not be allowed (of course after **.75**, only 1 is allowed)

so far the regular expression(s) that I have to satisfy the above conditions is:

```
   /^[-+]?[0-9](\.[2|5|7]{1}[5|0]{1})?$/;
```

In my javascript I have:

```
  var catchfloat5 = /^[-+]?[0-9](\.[2|5|7]{1}[5|0]{1})?$/;
  var catchint2 = /^[1-9]$/;
```

the second regular expression is for matching integers 1-9.

and in the code I do:

```
   if(inputHours.match(catchfloat5) || inputHours.match(catchint2) ) { 
    //alert("Correct, you entered float or an int");
    return true;
```

}

The above code appears to do the job, but fails, because it allows the following inputs:

0.25
0.50
0.75

It does match 1.25, 1.50, 1.75 and so on.

How would I correct my regular expression to match: .25, .50 and .75?
I think the problem I have is: I do have a regular expression that might match negative decimal numbers also. When I try to get rid of the positive and negative symbols, 
I am breaking the expression.

I do have trouble understanding the role of the ? character also.
And my research comes from:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

---

What I am trying to accomplish is:
A regular expression that matches the inputs I described above
and also to learn a few fundaments of regular expressions in the process.

Comment: The `?` means "0 or 1 occurrences". So for example, the `[-+]?` means to match "-" or "+" once or not at all - basically, the sign is optional

Comment: "No positive or negative signs before the number are allowed"... then why on Earth do you have `[-+]?` in your regex?

Comment: I think I included the [+-] naively at first. Then I tried to get rid of it, but broke the expression

Comment: @user3825558 Did you also remove the `?` after it? A lone `?` would've broken the expression

Comment: I could be wrong, but wouldn't it be easier to do this validation with a little simple math instead of a regex ?

Comment: @adeneo But regexes are the answer to everything!!11!1one! :p Nah, you're right, this would be better with simple math. `val >= 1 && val < 10 && val % 0.25 == 0` would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
/^(?:[1-9]|[1-9]?\.(?:25|50|75))$/
```

It matches

- Any integer 1-9 other than zero
- 1-9 or empty string followed by fractions .25, .50, .75, up to any number; leading zeroes not allowed

If you want to match more digits, and optional leading signs, you can do

```
/^[-+]?(?:[1-9][0-9]*|(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?\.(?:25|50|75))$/
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but `[-+]` doesn't mean optional. The `?` the OP had made it optional, right?

Comment: Yes, the inputs I want to match, and the input I do not want matched, seem to work with your expression. I am testing now.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, you are wanting to match any multiple of 0.25 between 1 and 9.75 inclusive, where integers must not have the `.00` while halves must have `.50`?

If so, your regex is:

```
/^[1-9](?:\.25|\.50|\.75|)$/
```

To explain, this allows any number between 1 and 9 as the integer part, then one of `.25`, `.50`, `.75` or nothing.

If this is not what you were after, then please clarify your question because it took several minutes and multiple attempts to understand this much!

Comment: Exactly. I should have stated the requirements the way you did. What you have written is exactly what I want. To clarify further, I am also wanting to match the whole numbers 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 only.

Comment: This regex still works for that, note the empty or option.  You could also write this /^[1-9](?:\.25|\.50|\.75)?$/, although that is just my personal preference.  I find using the question mark easier to read.

Comment: @wolffer-east I was on the fence when writing, but decided that `|)` would be better here than `)?`, because it seemed to be more obvious that "or nothing" would be an option in the alternation.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Fair enough, it isn't a syntax I normally use which is why I found it more obscure.  Then again it is all personal preference (unless there is a performance benefit to one or the other, though I don't know) so whatever works!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can try:

```
function match(n) {

    if (n.match(/^(|[1-9])\.(25|50|75)$/)) { return true; }
    return false;
}

console.log(match('1.25')); // true
console.log(match('0.25')); // false
console.log(match('.75')); // true
console.log(match('2.70')); // false
console.log(match('2.751')); // false
console.log(match('12.75')); // false
console.log(match('2.00')); // false

/* explanation
^           starts from
(|[1-9])    nothing or a Number between 1 & 9
\.          literal dot/point
(25|50|75)  either 25 or 50 or 75
$           end here
*/
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Za9cU/3/)

Comment: You put the "beginning of string" `^` in a branch, your regex matches also 111111111111111111111111.25.

Comment: @user3825558 If it needs adjusting, let me know and I will fix it for you :)